# How to bind xml datatype from sqlserver in silverlight4 application?

Tags: silverlight-4.0

Hii i am new in silverlight. when i am trying to bind xml datatype from sqlserver to the silverlight application using wcf-ria service then at the load time it throws unmanaged exception?

so, How to bind xml datatype from sqlserver in silverlight4 application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xml Datatype will bind automatically with silverlight4 application when we use wcf-ria service and after that we can serialize and deserialize the xml format.